# Optimizing a very slow select max group by query on Sybase ASE 15.5

Tags: sql, database, performance, query-optimization, sap-ase

I have a very simple query on a table with 60 million rows :

`select id, max(version) from mytable group by id`

It returns 6 million records and takes more than one hour to run. I just need to run it once because I am transferring the records to another new table that I keep updated.

I tried a few things that didn't work for me but that are often suggested here on stackoverflow:

1. inner query with `select top 1 / order by desc`: it is not supported in Sybase ASE
2. `left outer join where a.version < b.version and b.version is null`: I interrupted the query after more than one hour and barely a hundred thousand records were found

I understand that Sybase has to do a full scan.

**Why could the full scan be so slow?**

**Is the slowness due to the Sybase ASE instance itself or specific to the query?**

**What are my options to reduce the running time of the query?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally the nonclustered index on (id, version desc) did the trick without having to change anything to the query. Index creation also takes one hour and the query responds in few seconds. But I guess it's still better than having another table that could cause data integrity issues.

Answer (score 1):

I am not intimately familiar with Sybase optimization.  However, your query is really slow.  Here are two ideas.

First, add an index on `mytable(id, version desc)`.  At a minimum, this is a *covering* index for the query, meaning that all columns used are in the index.  Sybase is probably smart enough to eliminate the `group by`.

Another option uses the same index, but with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.id
from mytable t
where t.version = (select max(t2.version)
                   from mytable t2
                   where t2.id = t.id
                  );
```

This would be a full table scan (a little expensive but not an hour's worth) and an index lookup on each row (pretty cheap).  The advantage of this approach is that you can select all the columns you want.  The disadvantage is that if two rows have the same maximum version for an id, you will get both in the result set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention there is already a clustered index on this table and dropping it is not an option. Plus, index creation and update stats would not take less than hour.

Comment: @Nicolas . . . I didn't mention anything about a clustered index or dropping any existing index.

Comment: "add an index on mytable(id, version desc)"  are you talking about a nonclustered index?

Comment: @Nicolas . . . Yes.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** : Here Nicolas a more precise answer. I have no particular experience with Sybase but I earned experience working with tones of data with a quite small server on Sql Server. From this experience, I learn that when you work with a large amount of data and your server doesn't have enough memory to deal with that amount of data, you will encounter bottlenecks (I guess it takes times to write the temporary results on the disk). I think it's your case (60 millions rows) but once again, I don't know Sybase and it depends of many factors as the numbers of columns mytable have and the amount of RAM your server have, etc ...

Here the results of a small experience I just did :

I run on Sql-Server and PostgreSQL those two queries.

Query 1 :

```
SELECT id, max(version)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id
```

Query 2 :

```
SELECT id, version
FROM
(
    SELECT id, version, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY version DESC) as RN
    FROM mytable
) q
WHERE q.rn = 1
```

On PostgreSQL, mytable has 2.878.441 rows.
Query#1 takes 31.458 sec and returns 1.200.146 rows.
Query#2 takes 41.787 sec and returns 1.200.146 rows.

On Sql Server, mytable has 1.600.010 rows.
Query#1 takes 6 sec and returns 537.232 rows.
Query#2 takes 10 sec and returns 537.232 rows.

So far, your query is always faster. So I tried on a bigger tables.

On PostgreSQL, mytable has now 5.875.134 rows.
Query#1 takes 100.915 sec and returns 2.796.800 rows.
Query#2 takes 98.805 sec and returns 2.796.800 rows.

On Sql Server, mytable has now 11.712.606 rows.
Query#1 takes **28 min 28 sec** and returns 6.262.778 rows.
Query#2 takes **2 min 39 sec** and returns 6.262.778 rows.

Now we can make an assumption. In the first part on this experience. The two servers have enough memory to deal with the data, thus Group By is faster. The second part on this experiment might prove that too much data kill the performance of group by. To prevent the bottleneck ROW_NUMBER() seems to do the trick.

**Criticisms** : I don't have a bigger table on PostgreSQL nor I have a Sybase server at hand.

For this experiment I was using PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on x86_64 and SQL Server 2012 - 11.0-2100.60 (X64)

Maybe Nicolas this experiment will help you.

Comment: I'm curious too. IMHO the `PARTITION BY` is pretty much the same amount of work as the `GROUP BY`, but with the `MAX` it can keep just the one value while streaming through the data while using the `ROW_NUMBER()` and dumping all the results in a temp-table means it needs too keep every single value in "memory" for the entire operation.

Comment: I'll do some benchmark for tomorrow and I will update my too quick answer.

Comment: I've just tested your query and it is not supported. Incorrect syntax near keyword 'OVER'.

Comment: My bad ... Row_number exists only on certain version of Sybase (apparently IQ). I have few questions : - why is it important that your query last less than a hour ? For 60 millions of rows, it's not that bad. - how many columns do you have in mytable ? - can you edit your post and give us the details of your clustered index and if exists others indexs ?

Comment: Actually it's not THAT important and it's still OK for a one-shot. I just assumed that I could do better and I was also wondering if there was some problem with the DB behind that.

Comment: As I wrote I think your query is too big for high performance. There is just one thing I don't get. I think you can't have a clustered index on ID if there is   some duplicates of ID in mytable. But anyway. You should try to add this index and run your first query again (max(version) ... group by) : create index index_mytable_id_version on mytable(id, version)

Answer (score 0):

the function max() does not help the optimizer to use the index.
Perhaps you should create a function-based index on max(version):
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1550/html/sqlug/CHDDHJIB.htm

Comment: I didn't know about this feature. Should I create index on id,max(version) or only max(version) ?

Comment: I've just tested and aggregate functions are not allowed in index. It only works with non-aggregate functions like lower or upper.